# Defining time dimension in Mondrain Schema?

Tags: postgresql, olap, mondrian, saiku

I am trying to define time dimension in Mondrian schema. In Mondrian time dimension it require 3 level-type must be  `Years`, `Quarters`, `Months`.

But my table contain only one date field. So how it is possible?

Can I use postgreSQL query in `Mondrian`? So I can use 3 query to select `Years`, `Quarters` and `Month` from single date field.

Comment: You cannot add columns `year, quarter, month` into you table? Or create view based on this table? Mondrian can use views.

Comment: No, Because its standard, I have Idea like <Level name="Year" column=Some sql syntax which extract year  type="Numeric" uniqueMembers="true" /> Same like month and day from single field.

Comment: Mondrian has `view` [element](http://mondrian.pentaho.com/documentation/schema.php#XML_View) where view can be defined using standard SQL.

Comment: I added view but it result to in blank cube. I wrote my view in answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create simple table with only one date column:

```
create table tmp_cube as (select generate_series('2011-01-01'::date, '2012-01-01'::date, '1 day')::date gs);
```

Create dummy cube:

```
<Schema name="New Schema1">
  <Cube name="Test" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="tmp_cube" schema="public" alias="">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="TimeDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="gs" name="Time Dimension">
      <Hierarchy name="New Hierarchy 0" visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="gs">
        <View alias="test_view">
          <SQL dialect="generic">SELECT gs, extract(year from gs) as year, extract(quarter from gs) as quarter, extract(month from gs) as month FROM tmp_cube</SQL>
        </View>
      <Level name="Year" visible="true" column="year" type="Integer" internalType="int" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeYears">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Quarter" visible="true" column="quarter" type="Integer" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeQuarters">
        </Level>
        <Level name="Month" visible="true" column="month" type="Integer" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="Count Rows" column="gs" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

Now I see in Saiku:

[image]